# How can I get a list of currently running modal operators?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

Here I found [a working solution using ctypes](https://blenderartists.org/t/detect-if-modal-operator-is-running/1204971/2) which allows to find out if any modal operator is currently running. I am not good in C and don't understand how it works. But I'm sure someone does, so is there a way to find out exactly which modal operators are currently running, and get a list of them (or their `bl_idname`)? As the Blender API only provides a few `bpy.app.handlers` which cover only several specific cases this would be a nice solution to make custom handlers for all other modal operators not included in the `bpy.app.handlers`.

For example for my add-on I would like to launch from my custom Modal Operator `bpy.ops.render.opengl` Operator in series in `('INVOKE_DEFAULT')` mode to be able to see a preview and abort this process at any time - but there's no handler in the API which would tell me when `bpy.ops.render.opengl` is over, and I can't figure out how to catch the moment when it returns `{"FINISHED"}`.

Comment: By the way it seems the first Ctypes solution works only with Python Operators in Blender. I've tried to launch `bpy.ops.render.opengl('INVOKE_DEFAULT')`, which is written in C as I know, and use this solution together with `threading.Timer()` to catch the moment where all modal operators stop running. And it doesn't catch any modal operator while `bpy.ops.render.opengl` is in progress. Pity, it could be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use something like the following to know when a modal operator has finished (see disclaimer).  Note: I'm summarizing code from another project, and I haven't tested the code below... it *almost certainly* has bugs, but it will get you close.

```py
class RenderOpenGLWrapped(Operator):
    bl_idname = 'render.opengl_wrapped'
    bl_label = 'Wraps render.opengl'
    # other options?

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return bpy.ops.render.opengl.poll(context)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        bpy.ops.render.opengl('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        last_ops = context.window.operators
        last_op_name = last_ops[-1].bl_idname if last_ops else None
        was_cancelled = (last_op_name != bpy.ops.render.opengl.idname())
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

this works because modal operators are pushed onto a stack.  here the wrapper object is pushed on the stack, then `render.opengl` is pushed on.  The window manager will call `modal` of the topmost operator, which is `render.opengl`. the wrapper's `modal` will not get called until `render.opengl` has finished.

disclaimer: this assumes `modal` for `render.opengl` doesn't return `{'PASS_THROUGH'}`!

If you're interested in knowing if there are *any* operators actively running modal, I just submitted the [D15546 patch](https://developer.blender.org/D15546).